# How to get data from JSON file in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get data from JSON file in my autofill text box, but eventually it's not working. Here is my code:

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "DemoJson.json",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {//alert("gfdg");
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And DemoJson.json contain data same as like this link does

```
http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific than just "it's not working". Are there errors in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)? What does it do and what is it supposed to do? Which library are you using?

Comment: Why are u sending data to the json file?

Comment: iam using jquery-1.9.1.js. and my city textbox supposed to populated with the data. @juhana

Comment: jQuery doesn't have an `.autocomplete()` method out of the box. Which library are you using for it? Are there errors in the error console?

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the returned JSON.

below

```
success: function( data ) {
```

add this line:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: could you do an alert(data) there? that will help you debug, tell us what the response is

Comment: it does not enter in success block. but it goes to DemoJson.json

Comment: I just noticed, you have written "success:" at the wrong place

Comment: So where it supposed to be written @Naveed Hasan

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42335/discussion-between-naveed-hasan-and-subodh)